# Different Between OData And GData

Tags: odata, gdata, iqueryable

What is different between OData and GData?
Does OData has more advantages in .NET technologies vs GData or not?
In my WCF project I want to create IQueryable models and REST platform for client,I used to OData before but I'm excited to know more about GData and it's features.

Answer (score 7):

GData is obsolate and doesn't have such a wide support as OData - "Warning: Most newer Google APIs are not Google Data APIs." - [Google Data Protocol Page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/)